# How did the PSP firmware 5.03 HEN-C exploit work?

Tags: sony-playstation, handheld

On the historical PSP (PlayStation Portable) console on firmware version 5.03 there used to be a thumbnail-based exploit called HEN-C. It worked (under a race condition I presume since it didn't work every single time) by viewing a picture thumbnail of an splashed egg and a binary encoded (?) picture thumbnail, which was the payload itself I would presume. The exploit was used to load so called CFW (custom firmware) onto the device, which is basically a jailbroken/modified ROM.

My questions would be:

- I'm guessing the exploit used a flaw in the thumbnail parser, is that correct?
- How did it actually work?
- What was the exact flaw/programming mistake in the firmware that allowed this?
- Was there been any similar exploits on PC as well? (yes I've searched exploit-db.com already with no avail...)
- Is it possible to find the source code for it somewhere for historical reasons?

All I could find online, that is relevant (besides lots of YouTube videos with annoying buzzing in the background) is this source code for the newer procfw https://github.com/wicanr2/procfw, which appears to be irrelevant to the exploit apparently...

Comment: Sounds like a buffer overflow exploit, where data loaded into memory is not bounds checked and overflows into memory reserved for code. When the code is run, the data is interpreted instead.

Comment: And indeed it is... https://www.myce.com/news/Sonys-PSP-Firmware-v2_0-exploited-using-an-overflow-attack-10907/

Comment: @MarkWilliams this is firmware version 2 it seems? Also on the Security StackExchange there was already a comment that supposedly it was a memory corruption bug, so there's a conflict kind of here. But thanks for the info nonetheless.

Comment: @SirMuffington Well, a buffer overflow is a type of memory corruption bug...